# Image Not getting binded in gridview from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-2008-r2

[image: This is my UI .. just see the last column.. I am getting such kind of image][image: Image show how data is stored for image in databse]Following is my code... I am trying to store image in database. I have used varbinary(MAX) datatype for storing data bytes in database. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
    int qtype = Convert.ToInt32(ddl_q_Type.SelectedValue);
                var getQ = (from q in obj.QuestionRegistrations
                            orderby q.QueCode ascending
                            where q.QueQuesType == qtype && q.QueLanguageCode == 1
                            select new { q.QueCode, q.QueQuestion }
                                ).ToArray();


                index = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["index"].ToString()) + 1;
                ViewState["index"] = index;
                previosIndex = index - 1;
                ViewState["previosIndex"] = previosIndex;
                txt_question.Text = getQ[index].QueQuestion;
                lblqcode.Text = getQ[index].QueCode.ToString();


                int qcode = Convert.ToInt32(lblqcode.Text);
                var options = (from opt in obj.QuestionAndOptionsMappings
                               where opt.QueMapQuestionCode == qcode
                               select new { opt.QueMapOptions, opt.QueMapCorrectAnswer, opt.QueMapId, opt.QueMapImage }
                                   ).ToList();


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Columns.Add("QueMapOptions", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("QueMapId", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("QueMapImage", typeof(string));

                foreach (var y in options)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["QueMapOptions"] = y.QueMapOptions;
                    dr["QueMapId"] = y.QueMapId;
                    dr["QueMapImage"] = (Byte[])y.QueMapImage;

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

This code for storing the image in databse

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                FileUpload fp = (FileUpload)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("fp");
                Label lblmapid = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("lblmapid");
                bool e1 = fp.HasFile;
                int mapiidd = Convert.ToInt32(lblmapid.Text);
                if (fp.HasFile)
                {
                    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fp.FileName;
                    fp.SaveAs(path);
                    byte[] imageBytes =
                        File.ReadAllBytes(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fp.FileName);
                    int qcodelbl = Convert.ToInt32(lblqcode.Text);
                    QuestionAndOptionsMapping qmap = new QuestionAndOptionsMapping();

                    var update = obj.QuestionAndOptionsMappings.Where(q => q.QueMapId == mapiidd && q.QueMapQuestionCode == qcodelbl)
                        ;
                    update.SingleOrDefault().QueMapImage = imageBytes;
                    obj.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
```

ASPX code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OPTIONS" HeaderStyle-Width="55%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Option" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QueMapOptions") %>' Height="40px"
                                        Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub Section" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblmapid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("QueMapId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub Section" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Chk_correct_Ans" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub Section" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fp" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub Section" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("QueMapImage") %>' Height="80px"
                                        Width="100px" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Is your image getting saved to the database properly?

Comment: @Sam : Yes.... in binary it is getting stored..

Comment: Rather than have us guess what is going wrong, why dont you explain the error you are having?

Comment: @paqogomez : I am not getting any error.. The image is getting binded.. but image is not visible.. thats it

Comment: @Sam : please see my edit for screen shot of my database table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can't just bind a binary column to a `GridView` column. you need to make use of `Response.BinaryWrite` method.

Here are few steps to follow to achieve what you want

1. Create a generic handler to read binary data. We'll call it **ImageHandler.ashx**. Make sure you have the primary key of the table to be passed to this handler. Write the handler code something like below (just an example).

   ```
   public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
       {
   ```

   string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;

   ```
           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

           cmd.CommandText = "Select [Content] from Images where ID =@ID";

           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

           cmd.Connection = conn;

           SqlParameter ImageID = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
           ImageID.Value = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];
           cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageID);
           conn.Open();
           SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           dReader.Read();
           context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dReader["Content"]);
           dReader.Close();
           conn.Close();
       }
   ```
2. And call the handler like this.

   ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" + Eval("ID")%>'

instead of

```
ImageUrl='<%#Eval("QueMapImage") %>'
```

[Here's](http://codedisplay.com/display-images-in-gridview-from-sql-server-database-table-using-asp-net-c-vb-net/) a complete example from where I extracted above examples.

All the best!

Comment: If i have more than 1 rows then, only first row's image is getiing displayed for rest of he rows in grid.

Comment: It can't be you must be doing something wrong. update your question with code

Comment: Adding to @Sam Answer once you create the Handler, in the handler you will have to get QueMapID to that you need context.Request.QueryString["QueMapId"]; in the handler then make DB call and in the Grid View ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" + Eval("QueMapId")%>'